# How to use NSUserDefaults to store an array of dictionaries

Tags: arrays, swift, persistence, nsuserdefaults

Trying to store an array of dictionaries with `NSUserDefaults`.

```
var theTasks: [[String:Any]] = [["num":1,"title":"example","colour":"red"]] 

let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject(theTasks, forKey: "myTasks")
    defaults.synchronize()

let selected = theTasks[1]
```

Gives error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[[String:Any]]' to expected argument of type 'AnyObject?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Swift 3.x**

In Swift 3 it has changed so now it needs to be saved as `[Any]` Any Array and use UserDefaults array(forKey:) method to load it:

```
let theTasks: [Any] = [["num": 1, "title": "example", "colour": "red"]]
UserDefaults.standard.set(theTasks, forKey: "myTasks")
if let loadedTasks = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "myTasks") as? [[String: Any]] {
    print(loadedTasks)
}
```

---

```
var theTasks: [[String: Any]] {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "myTasks") as? [[String: Any]] ?? []
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue as [Any], forKey: "myTasks")
    }
}
```

---

---

**Swift 2.x**

You just need to save it as a `AnyObject` array and use `NSUserDefaults` method `arrayForKey` to load it:

```
let theTasks: [AnyObject] = [["num": 1, "title": "example", "colour": "red"]]
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(theTasks, forKey: "myTasks")
if let loadedTasks = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("myTasks") as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
    print(loadedTasks)
}
```

You can also create a computed property with a getter and a setter to do all the work behind the scenes for you as follow:

```
var theTasks: [[String: AnyObject]] {
    get {
        return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("myTasks") as? [[String: AnyObject]] ?? []
    }
    set {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(newValue as [AnyObject], forKey: "myTasks")
    }
}

print(theTasks)                // [["title": example, "colour": red, "num": 1]]
theTasks[0]["title"] = "another example"

print(theTasks)               // [["title":  another example, "colour": red, "num": 1]]
```

Comment: This won't work as `theTask` are required to be `[[String:Any]]` to allow editing of the of the content.

Comment: I have updated my question to contain new variable `selected` if I change to `[AnyObject]` I get the error `Cannot subscript a value of type '[AnyObject'`

Comment: I know its not meant for thanks the comments but @LeoDabus thank you very much, I did not even know about the getter and setter. Works great! :)

Answer (score -1):

Just call the `.setObject()` method directly from `NSUserDefaults()`and it should work fine.

`NSUserDefaults().setObject(theTasks, forKey: "myTasks")`