# Tuples in Property List Swift

Tags: swift, tuples, property-list

I want to create a property list to build up a graph using adjacent list representation.

So in the property list, I want to have a dictionary ([String: Array]). The string will be the node, the array will store its neighbors.
Inside the Array, I would like to have (String, Int) tuples, the String for the neighbor, the Int for the weight (each tuple represents an edge incident to the node).

The problem is that I cannot have tuples inside Property List. I could use Dictionary, but it seems an array of dictionary with only one item inside that dictionary is not worth it. Any better solutions? Thanks!

Comment: You can't save tuples. You already know you need an array of dictionaries http://stackoverflow.com/a/34773248/2303865 this saves to NSUserDeafults but you can adapt to save to a plist

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes I do want to use plist. So there is no other choice, I have to use a dictionary which contains just one element?

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka Tuple type is not supported by plist. Only Array, Dictionary, Number, NSData, String and NSDate

Comment: @LeoDabus Ok. I will use dictionary for now.

Comment: @Huang I confused your question, so deleted my original comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
 let node                           = "node"
 let incident                       = ( "edge1", 12 ) 
 var dictionary:[String:Array<Any>] = [:]
 dictionary[node]                   = [ incident.0, incident.1 ]
```

This should give you a dictionary with a string and an array from your tuples

Comment: Thanks! Actually in the end I didn't bother to create plists. Instead I build the graph using some helper class, which is similar to your answer suggested. :)